# Jquery silent error in drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to use an uncotroversial piece of code to change the background color
of a div when the mouse hovers over it.

Currently, my install of drupal refuses to register the hover event, I have tried substituting my code with a console.log('hovering') and I still get nothing.

here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/tmXfW/2/

```
( function($) {
        var msg = $().jquery;
        console.log(msg);
        $('div.quicklink-row').hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass('blue-link');
        }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('blue-link');

        });
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your functionality in a [Drupal Behavior](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors). This will make it work even if elements on the page change via ajax and whatnot.

So the following:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myCustomModule = {
    attach: function() {
      //var msg = $().jquery;
      //console.log(msg);
      $('div.quicklink-row').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('blue-link');
      }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('blue-link');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);​
```

But aside from that.... why are you using Javascript for something that can be done so simply with CSS?

```
div.quicklink-row:hover {
  background: #00F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The have been several issues with the jsfiddle code.

1. The most suspected line is this:
   `var msg = $().jquery;`
   Try changing it to:
   `var msg = $.fn.jquery;`
2. The jsfiddle has been reported to insert some invisible characters producing the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` errors in the console ([see this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal))
3. Your code contains only the encapsulation wrapper, but inside it lacks the `$.ready(function(){})` or its equivalent.

So I typed your code from scratch, making the changes (1) and (3) and it worked fine.